# SQL - Select not repeated rows from 2 tables?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables (perhaps they are badly built).

table1

```
id  |  word  |  user
1   |  a     |  me
2   |  b     |  dad
3   |  c     |  mom
4   |  d     |  sister
```

table2

```
id  |  word  |  user
1   |  a     |  me
2   |  b     |  dad
```

I want to show all rows from table1 excluding the rows from table2 which are equal to table1. In this case, the select must display row 3 and 4 from table.

Thanks.

Comment: And now it's been retagged again lol

Comment: You have not specified the database so what RDBMS are you using? You have different options based on that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * from Table1
   Except
     Select * from Table2
```

Comment: @frankie3: also (probably) most efficient and most readable. Please tag your rdbms next time since some functions are not available for all databases.

Answer (score 4):

You did not specify what RDBMS but you can use `NOT EXISTS` in all databases:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (select *
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.word = t2.word
                    and t1.user = t2.user 
                    -- add other columns here for comparison including id)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfe7e/4)

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM Table2);
```

[Predicate NOT IN Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09d68/5)

**Or:** using a `LEFT JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

[LEFT JOIN Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09d68/4)

Answer (score 1):

As you did not specify what flavour of SQL you are using, it is probably wise to steer clear of EXCEPTS and use standard ANSI SQL. So this is a case for using a left outer join.

```
SELECT t1.*  
FROM table1 AS t1  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2  
        ON t1.word = t2.word
        AND t1.user = t2.user
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: You need another condition, he needs an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) (SQL-Server >= 2005)

```
SELECT id, word, user
FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT id, word, user
FROM Table2;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfe7e/5/0)